# Migrating from XP on a Samsung NC10

Tags: samsung

I've still got the NC10 as my main machine. I attach a 22" monitor, the keyboard is comfy and it can "almost" slip in a big pocket! Samsung software makes it easy to manage the machine. Great machine for what I do with OPen GL apps and a browser. XP is unsupported, viruses and poison pills abound and the while browsing the machine is latent.

I need a liteweight OS less prone to infection but I would like to preserve the Samsung software o have equivalent functionality in Linux.

Tried it once and got to a menu but then the machine froze. What's the most functional version for my machine NC10 with 2GB ram. Any gochas? Driver issues?

Thanks in advance for any precious advice.

Comment: What is Samsung NC10?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Answer (score 0):

I love my little NC10! Lubuntu runs pretty smoothly on an NC10, and that was with the 1GB of RAM. Lubuntu also gave me longer battery life than XP. I ran Lubuntu on it until about a year ago and never had any issues. I then turned it into a tiny home server, but this isn't what you want.

You will not have the Samsung software, however Lubuntu out of the box should do everything the Samsung software did (personally even when I used it with XP I hated the Samsung software and removed it).