# A lot of problems with the instalation with xubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I every one, i want to install xubuntu desktop in a samsung nc10, with 1GB of ram and an intel Atom N270 with 1,60 GHZ.
So i want to install the xubuntu but when i try to install and run xubuntu without install to configurate somethings in the PC, so all is running normal but a read error appears in the screen six time and next appears an error in something with a usb port, and appears the initramfs console and there i cannot do anything and is like a limbo in the console.
here is the complete text.

```
20.740074 usb 1-6 : device descriptor read/64, error -110
35.956102 usb 1-6 : device descriptor read/64, error -110
41.284104 usb 1-6 : device descriptor read/64, error -110
56.500160 usb 1-6 : device descriptor read/64, error -110
67.124083 usb 1-6 :device not accepting adress 5, error -110
77.644202 usb 1-6 :device not accepting adress 6, error -110
77.644420 usb usb1-port6: unable to enumerate USB device
```

(in this part appears a loading screen with xubuntu logo in blue with the word xubuntu )

```
Busy Box v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built in shell (ash)
Enter "help" for a list of built in commands.

(initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system
```

I need to say i use 2 programs to do a USB boot, A linux program and rufus i tried with the two programs a are the same thing

Please help me i need it 
"THANK YOU"

Comment: But i cannot do anything i cannot install or use the OS, the only thing i cando is use help yn the menu or the initframs

Comment: I'm a little confused: "try to install and run xubuntu without install"?  it sounds like you're trying to 'try ubuntu' or use it in 'live' mode first, but are getting device (read) errors and it can't boot. After downloading did you verify your download was correct (ie. md5sum verify, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) before writing to thumb-drive; or you had errors writing to the thumb-drive?  (try booting it on another pc to verify its okay) ...

Comment: Beside @guiverc suggestion. Try different (1) USB flashdisk and (2) USB Port (avoid using USB hubs). Also could you add the question which xubuntu release you have used?

Comment: This link indicates that it should work, [Migrating from XP on a Samsung NC10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/657313/migrating-from-xp-on-a-samsung-nc10?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

Comment: Maybe these links can help too, Lubuntu 16.04.1 LTS is supported until April 2019. [Lubuntu installation on NC10 Netbook not working](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2332316) and [How to select the version and flavour of Ubuntu](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13540865#post13540865)

Comment: Okay i`m using the 16.04.1 xubuntu and yeah i need change "run ubuntu without install"but the same thing is when i use diferent usb, deiferent port and the oprion install ubuntu all is the same thing every solution that i was found nothing works